# how to make Map overlay looks transparent

Tags: ios

I have Map overlay showing filled circle. The issue I need this circle to look transparent, so that user could see the map view under the circle overlay. below is my code:

```
-(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id)overlay 
{
    MKCircleView* circleView = [[MKCircleView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay] ;
    //circleView.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
    circleView.strokeColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    circleView.fillColor=[[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];

    return circleView;
}
```

Is there any `MKCirecleView` property which set the view to be transparent or is there any other workaround?

Comment: What's wrong with the above?  Setting circleView.alpha to 0 will make the whole circle disappear.

Comment: I don't want it to completely disappear. only some degree of trasnparency so that user could see the circle overlay but also see the map beanath it.

Comment: So the above should work.  Reduce the alpha component to increase the transparency.

Comment: Thanks ... it works!! if you like answer the question and I will flag it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Anna Karenina ... the above solution worked

```
circleView.alpha=0.5
```